# When submitting a GitHub issue with a new unit test demonstrating the bug, how to submit?

Tags: git, github

When submitting a GitHub issue describing a new bug, it's neat to add a unit test that fails to help show what's going wrong. What's the best practice for submitting that unit test -- a new branch, a pull request, a gist, or otherwise?

A new branch would presumably just sit in the submitter's forked version of the repo. That would work, but I'm not sure if that's really the best way. A pull request presents the branch for merging, but that seems wrong because unless a fix is present, you don't actually want to merge in the failing test yet (unless you would choose to merge it to a feature branch). A gist would do the job, I suppose, but  but requires the submitter to take a unit test that is present in their clone of the project and copy and paste it outside, which seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

What would be considered a best practice? Obviously one answer is "ask the project maintainer." Suppose I am the project maintainer. What kind of workflow should I consider enforcing for people submitting bugs with unit tests that demonstrate the bug (and therefore fail)? Would I do something different for a bug I intended to fix quickly, vs. something which would sit in backlog?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would encourage either posting the unit test as a code block directly into the Github issue, or posting a link to a Gist (preferable as it allows code reviewing and versioning).

I wouldn't expect someone to open a PR unless they have committed some code changes that make that unit test pass.

Answer (score 0):

A pull request makes it easiest for the maintainers to get the test and run it for themselves. That you do not actually want the branch to be merged is not as relevant as the ease of maintainers to run the test.

Ideally projects have already CI set up for PRs, so the maintainers will automatically also get the test failure visible in github with all logs, and they can easily add comments to the PR to discuss details with you about the test failure.